# Не могу найти причину возникновения ошибки cannot set property 'classname' of undefined

Tags: javascript, html, css

Не могу понять причину появления ошибки:

> cannot set property 'classname' of undefined.

Из-за чего она возникает в данном примере ?

```js
var slides = document.querySelectorAll('.sliderPage__slides .sliderPage__slide');
var currentSlide = 0;
var slideInterval = setInterval(nextSlide, 2000);

function nextSlide() {
  slides[currentSlide].className = 'sliderPage__slide';
  currentSlide = (currentSlide + 1) % slides.length;
  slides[currentSlide].className = 'sliderPage__slide sliderPage__showing';
}
```

```css
.sliderPage {
  width: 100%;
  height: 90vh
}

.sliderPage__slides {
  position: relative;
  height: 300px;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  list-style-type: none
}

.sliderPage__slide {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: opacity 1s;
  font-size: 40px;
  padding: 40px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: #333;
  color: #fff
}

.sliderPage__showing {
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 2
}

.sliderPage__slide:nth-of-type(1) {
  background: red
}

.sliderPage__slide:nth-of-type(2) {
  background: green
}

.sliderPage__slide:nth-of-type(3) {
  background: blue
}

.sliderPage__slide:nth-of-type(4) {
  background: purple
}

.sliderPage__slide:nth-of-type(5) {
  background: orange
}

.sliderPage__slide:nth-of-type(6) {
  background: gold
}
```

```html
<div class="sliderPage__slider">

  <ul class="sliderPage__slides">
    <li class="sliderPage__slide sliderPage__showing">1</li>
    <li class="sliderPage__slide">2</li>
    <li class="sliderPage__slide">3</li>
    <li class="sliderPage__slide">4</li>
    <li class="sliderPage__slide">5</li>

  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: скорее всего, у Вас скрипт отрабатывает раньше, чем подгружается html

Comment: точно, спасибо огромное, добавил подключение js перед закрывающим </body> и заработало

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var slides = document.querySelectorAll('.sliderPage__slides .sliderPage__slide');
var currentSlide = 0;
var slideInterval = setInterval(nextSlide, 2000);

function nextSlide() {
  console.log("nextSlide 1:", currentSlide, slides.length);
  slides[currentSlide].className = 'sliderPage__slide';
  currentSlide = (currentSlide + 1) % slides.length;
  console.log("nextSlide 2:", currentSlide, slides.length);
  slides[currentSlide].className = 'sliderPage__slide sliderPage__showing';
}
```

```css
.sliderPage {
  width: 100%;
  height: 90vh
}

.sliderPage__slides {
  position: relative;
  height: 300px;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  list-style-type: none
}

.sliderPage__slide {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: opacity 1s;
  font-size: 40px;
  padding: 40px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: #333;
  color: #fff
}

.sliderPage__showing {
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 2
}

.sliderPage__slide:nth-of-type(1) {
  background: red
}

.sliderPage__slide:nth-of-type(2) {
  background: green
}

.sliderPage__slide:nth-of-type(3) {
  background: blue
}

.sliderPage__slide:nth-of-type(4) {
  background: purple
}

.sliderPage__slide:nth-of-type(5) {
  background: orange
}

.sliderPage__slide:nth-of-type(6) {
  background: gold
}
```

```html
<div class="sliderPage__slider">

  <ul class="sliderPage__slides">
    <li class="sliderPage__slide sliderPage__showing">1</li>
    <li class="sliderPage__slide">2</li>
    <li class="sliderPage__slide">3</li>
    <li class="sliderPage__slide">4</li>
    <li class="sliderPage__slide">5</li>

  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: К сожалению не помогло (

Comment: На встроенной демке вижу что все работает так как нужно, но только стоит мне скопировать этот же код себе в документ и запустить в браузере, то ошибка остается вся та же

Comment: @AntonKylbashnyi Добавьте вызовы `console.log` в `nextSlide` как у меня. Что в консоли браузера перед тем, как там появляется ошибка?

Comment: Проблема заключалась в том что classList обращался к элементам, которые якобы еще небыли созданы в ДОМ. Подключил скрипт перед закрывающим боди и все начало работать. Спасибо огромное за помощь